# Syntax Error T_Variable

Tags: php, syntax

```
 <?php
     class CSS {
         public $base   = '/public/stylesheets';
         public $global = $base . '/global.css'; 
     }
 ?>
```

When I open up my site, this appears "`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$base' (T_VARIABLE)`"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php you cannot use any operator, or reference a variable, during class property declarations. You'd have to initialize the property value in the class constructor :

```
class CSS {
      public $base   = '/public/stylesheets';
      public $global; 

      public function __construct() {
          $this->global = $this->base . '/global.css';
      }
}
```

Which is specified in this php manual quote :

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may**
>   **include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant**
>   **value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and**
>   **must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**

Ref. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 1):

You can not use variable in another variable. Use class constant instead like below :

```
<?php
class CSS {
    const CSSPATH = '/public/stylesheets';
    public $base   = '/public/stylesheets';
    public $global = CSSPATH . '/global.css'; 
}
?>
```